# Matlab's solve: Solution not satisfying the equation

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I am trying to solve equations with this code:

```
a = [-0.0008333 -0.025 -0.6667 -20];
length_OnePart = 7.3248;
xi = -6.4446;
yi = -16.5187;
syms x y
[sol_x,sol_y] = solve(y == poly2sym(a), ((x-xi)^2+(y-yi)^2) == length_OnePart^2,x,y,'Real',true);

sol_x = sym2poly(sol_x);
sol_y = sym2poly(sol_y);
```

The sets of solution it is giving are (-23.9067,-8.7301) and (11.0333,-24.2209), which are not even satisfying the equation of circle. How can I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to solve for the intersection of the cubic and the circle, i.e., where `y==poly2sym(a)` equals `(x-xi)^2+(y-yi)^2==length_OnePart^2` it looks like `solve` may be confused about something when the circle is represented parametrically rather than as single valued functions. It might also have to do with the fact that `x` and `y` are not independent solutions, but rather that the latter depends on the former. It also could depend on the use of a numeric solver in this case. `solve` seems to work fine with similar inputs to yours, so you might [report this behavior to the MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/) to see what they think.

In any case, here is a better, more efficient way to to tackle this as a root-solving problem (as opposed to simultaneous equations):

```
a = [-0.0008333 -0.025 -0.6667 -20];
length_OnePart = 7.3248;
xi = -6.4446;
yi = -16.5187;
syms x real
f(x) = poly2sym(a);
sol_x = solve((x-xi)^2+(f(x)-yi)^2==length_OnePart^2,x)
sol_y = f(sol_x)
```

which returns:

```
sol_x =

 0.00002145831413371390464567553686047
    -13.182825373861454619370838716408


sol_y =

 -20.000014306269544436430325843024
 -13.646590348358951818881695033728
```

Note that you might get slightly more accurate results (one solution is clearly at `0,-20`) if you represent your coefficients and parameters more precisely then just four decimal places, e.g., `a = [-1/1200 -0.025 -2/3 -20]`. In fact, `solve` might be able to find one or more solutions exactly, if you provide exact representations.

Also, in your code, the calls to `sym2poly` are doing nothing other than converting back to floating-point (`double` can be used for this) as the inputs are not in the form of symbolic polynomial equations.

Comment: Thanx alot...
could you plz help me to understand why is it not giving answer with `solve()` function. Bcoz it looks like solving same equations from both the above mentioned methods.

Comment: @Ankush: I've updated the first part of my answer to be more nuanced. You really should be solving in a manner similar to what I show, but I think that `solve` still should be able to handle what what you gave it (usually it does in some tests I tried) and return sensible output or an error – I have no idea what the values you got pertain to.